# Power Apps - Using Dataverse Tables that show under Data Source

Tags: powerapps, dataverse

Just starting to work with Power Apps.  Creating a Help Desk app using the template, but I want to add to it.  Right now I am using Lists to store data, but would prefer using a database - Dataverse is an option.  Reason - I want to keep a log of dates and work performed in order to accomplish a task and Lists isn't ideal for creating a relational database. Do not currently have SQL in the cloud. My question is - there are all these tables that come built in with Dataverse but I cannot find a list describing the tables.  I find a list describing the fields, but not tables.  Does anyone know where I can find a list?  I've been searching for days!  I know I can add each one to the app and look at the fields and try to figure out what their field name means, but it would be so helpful if there was a list.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Tables inside a Dataverse instance (Power Apps or Dynamics 365) are based on the Common Data Model.

You can find more info inside this repository:

https://github.com/Microsoft/CDM

In particular the Visual Entity Navigator:

https://microsoft.github.io/CDM/